# How android is scaling PNGs

Tags: android

I'm new in android. And I'm curuous how android is scaling it's PNGs.
For example in ...**\sdk\platforms\android-19\data\res\drawable-xhdpi** there is a **popup_inline_error_holo_light_am.9.png**. (Sorry I don't have needed reputation to post the image)

First I don't understand the black and red lines on the edges of the PNG.
Second for example when you call ***EditText.setError("Some kind of error")***, the PNG will auto scale it self so it can contain all the error message, but the red "arrow/pointer", that points up, of the PNG won't stretch and will stay the same. The other thing is that the black and red lines from the PNG doesn't show when the error popup in the application.

How is this happening ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the use of 9patch PNG?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353076/what-is-the-use-of-9patch-png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's called a **9 patch** (mind the extension: **.9.png**).

The black lines (left and up) are markers for **stretching** (vertically and horizontally, respectively).
The black lines (right and down) are for defining some **padding**.

Very nice tutorial here: http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/
Reference page: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Comment: Nice thing, uh? with a **small** png you can fill a wide area, leaving some parts unscaled (if ever). So, if cleverly used, these images can be a powerful tool.